# .slideToggle hover on div jquery

Tags: jquery, hover, slidetoggle

I want to be able to slideToggle a div on hover, but it is not working.. Here is the code:

```
<div class='slide-header'>
        header....
</div>

<div class='slide-content'>
       Content..................
</div>

<script>
$(".slide-header").hover(function () {
    $(".slide-content").slideToggle("slow");
});
</script>

<style><!-- initially, I don't want to display .slide-content -->
    .slide-content { display:none; }
</style>
```

How can I .slideToggle on hover? Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rfUWg/

Comment: This works fine. See if you have any errors in the console...

Comment: Do you have jQuery referenced properly? Do you have it inside a document ready function?

Comment: Thanks @idor_brand. Forgot document ready... Stupid.. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".slide-header").hover(function () {
    $(".slide-content").stop().slideDown("slow");
}, function(){
    $(".slide-content").stop().slideUp("slow");
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work for some reason..

Comment: Sorry it does work. Forgot document ready.. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome :) .. If that is the case you might be missing document.ready in the other case too which you posted.. That should work as well..

Comment: it slides Up and Down 5 times after one hoverOn and hoverOut. Why? I found out - .stop() has to be added

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function:

```
$(function(){
    $(".slide-header").hover(function () {
        $(".slide-content").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```